# ActiveMQ - Docker version - Connection refused: no further information

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, activemq-classic

In a Spring Boot 2.7 application, on startup I connect to the 61616 port of the ActiveMQ Docker image. Often I get errors that the application cannot connect to ActiveMQ. Sometimes I have to remove the Docker image and/or a Window 10 folder before everything works again. At other times just restarting my Windows desktop is sufficient.

**Question**: How can I prevent these connection issues?

> o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS
> Connection for destination 'inmemory.queue.mutatieverslag' - retrying
> using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=12,
> maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL:
> tcp://127.0.0.1:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
> refused: no further information

**Software config:**

ActiveMQ runs in a Docker Desktop environment with a docker-compose file. The Java application is started seperately. Because I export the port, the port should be accessable to localhost.

The Docker image is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  activemq:
    image: symptoma/activemq:latest
    ports:
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    volumes:
      - /k/data/var/activemq/data:/data/activemq
      - /k/data/var/activemq/log:/var/log/activemqnetworks
networks:
  backend:
```

**Diagnosis:**

While starting the ActiveMQ Docker image, I can see in the log:

> 2023-04-12 16:18:32  INFO | Listening for connections at:
> tcp://0dbd01e3b73c:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600

Doing a "netstat -nao" gives a list without the 61616 port. Is this correct?

Bash shell (Windows) with curl telnet:
[image]

When performing a ping to that port, nothing is shown. Some suggested that this indicated that the server is not listening. Via the management port 8161 I can connect/browse to the ActiveMQ console.

Comment: It's clear that, generally speaking, you want to solve your Docker/ActiveMQ connectivity issue, but you've got a lot of interrelated questions and details along the way that make it hard to focus on underlying issue and provide a clear answer. The "devil is in the details" as they say so it's really important to focus on **one** thing at a time and provide only the details absolutely necessary to understand the problem. I recommend you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including an explanation of what  you see at each step.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using the hostname tcp://0dbd01e3b73c:61616?  Also, you can use some standard network tools to query the port independent of the ActiveMQ client code.  check out "curl telnet://..hostnam..:61616" .. etc

Comment: Connect to host string from the Docker image log does not work. Error: Reason: java.net.UnknownHostException: 017c2342d72e.  [2] Telnet/tcp with curl: the prefix of Url is unknown.

Comment: @Justin Bertram: Thank you. Now things are getting more clear, I removed all stuff that had nothing to do with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the port 61616 is not recommended by IANA : Internet Assigned Numbers Authority.

You should probarly map activemq port for another port range, like 9000:61616 using docker port mapping, and don't forget to change spring configuration to tcp://127.0.0.1:9000

Please, let me known if that fix your probleme.